# Doctrine object not setting foreig key when adding related entity

Tags: mysql, orm, doctrine, yaml, entity-relationship

I am using Doctrine 2 with CodeIgniter 2 and basically I want to achieve something like this:

```
 $product = $this->doctrine->em->find("Entities\Product", 1)
 $feature = new Entities\Feature;
 $feature->setName("foo");

 $product->addFeature($feature);

 $this->doctrine->em->persist($product);
 $this->doctrine->em->flush();
```

When persisting the feature object gets added to the database but has product_id set to null.
How do I make doctrine set the foreign key automatically.

I create both my classes as well as the table via the doctrine command line tool with the following YAML Markup

```
Entities\Product:
  type: entity
  table: products
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
  fields:
    name:
      type: string
      length: 50
  oneToMany:
    features:
      targetEntity: Feature
      mappedBy: product
      cascade: ["persist"]



Entities\Feature:
  type: entity
  table: features
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
  fields:
    name:
      type: string
      length: 50
  manyToOne:
    product:
      targetEntity: Product
      inversedBy: features
      joinColumn:
        name: product_id
        referencedColumnName: id
```

Edit:

of course I can fix the issue by changing the addFeature method in Product.php

```
public function addFeature(\Entities\Feature $features)
{
       $features->setProduct($this);
       $this->features[] = $features;
       return $this;
}
```

But since this should work without touching the code I'm guessing there's something wrong with my YAML markup/databasesetup

Answer (score 0):

"In a many-to-one relation the Many-side is the owning side by default, because it holds the foreign key."

Please refer this [link](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html#adding-bug-and-user-entities).

Comment: Yes it is. My problem is that it is not holding the foreign key by default because it is not being set.

Comment: Generally, Product probably has many-to-one of many-to-many relationship with features. If you product will have only one feature at the max but other products may have the same feature, then it is a many-to-one relationship with feature. If your product will have many features, and another product can share the feature, then it is a many-to-many relationship with feature.